# Matching colors for OpenGL on iOS and OS X

Tags: ios, macos, opengl, colors

I'm trying to match colors from UI mockups in my OpenGL app on iOS and OS X. When I enter the RGB values for colors, I get colors slightly different from the mockups, as confirmed by screenshots (and visually). From inspecting the values, it appears a slight gamma has been applied (colors are slightly darker, but black maps to black, and white to white), but much less prominent than raising to the 2.2 power. It's not that far off, but enough for me to notice, and I'd like to fully understand this (and be able to get the same colors my designer uses).

I read [TN2313](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2313/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014694-CH1-NONCOLORMANAGEDFRAMEWORKS-OPENGL___EXPLICIT_COLOR_MANAGEMENT_EXAMPLE), which seems to suggest applying a `sqrt` to the color values in the fragment shader, but that results in colors that are way off.

**What are the steps I need to take to match OpenGL colors to those in a PNG or PDF?**

Comment: Do you literally mean matching colors, as in matching the colors on your screen to print? Applying `sqrt` to color values would effectively do gamma correction for power-law 2.0 gamma, by the way. Most PDF and other such documents would probably be authored with sRGB (very roughly approximates 2.2 gamma) in mind. You'd use `pow (1.0 / 2.2)` to quickly approximate that. If you mean the former, matching colors to something printed, you need to get your display and/or printer calibrated and use an ICC profile.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I just mean on the screen. I'm trying to get my app colors to match PDF or PNG mockups. When I do `pow(color, 1.0/2.2)`, the colors are far from the mockup.

Comment: I see, I just read the article you linked to in full... and when it claims _"A square root is raising the value to the 1 over 2.2 power."_ I was just sort of left scratching my head. Square root is `^ 1 / 2`, that's basic arithmetic and I don't know what the author had in mind when he or she wrote that. Incidentally, most popular image formats are stored at 2.2 gamma but by the time you load the image data into your software gamma's already been corrected and you have linear RGB so you shouldn't need to apply any sort of correction when loading a JPG, PNG, etc.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that older versions of Mac OS X used to default to 1.8 gamma and a 2.2 gamma encoded PNG needs some form of correction to show up properly there. What version of OS X are you dealing with here?

Comment: I think that's just a mistake: they mean that `sqrt(x)` is an approximation of `pow(x,1/2.2)`. I'm not loading the PNG or PDF into my app. Rather, I'm manually entering the colors in the PNG as constants in the code. I'm using OS X 10.10.3.